# Xamarin Forms transparent element with border

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a `Frame` to create a border on various elements (Grid, StackLayout & ContentView) and need to now make the elements transparent; I tried setting the opacity of the Grid etc. but of course the `Frame` colour impacts the actual background colour.

```
<ContentPage BackgroundImage="some_image.png">
  <!-- ... -->
  <Frame BackgroundColor="Gray" Opacity="0.7" Padding="1" Margin="10">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="White" Opacity="0.7" Margin="20">
      <Label Text="..."/>
    </Grid>
  </Frame>
  <!-- ... -->
</ContentPage>
```

The `Grid` is rendered as expected but now the Frame grey background makes the white grid appear grey. Ideally I would like a white transparent Grid with a solid grey border, is this possible in Xamarin?

(Im using shared Xamarin forms project targeting iOS & Android)

Comment: For you lazy keyboard warriors like me who wanted a xaml pasta


<BoxView BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="1"/>              
 <BoxView BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LightColor}" HeightRequest="1" Opacity=".5"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" MinimumHeightRequest="1"/>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `BackgroundColor` to "Transparent" and `OutlineColor` to "Gray":

```
<ContentPage BackgroundImage="some_image.png">
  <!-- ... -->
  <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" OutlineColor="Gray" Opacity="0.7" Padding="1" Margin="10">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="White" Opacity="0.7" Margin="20">
      <Label Text="..."/>
    </Grid>
  </Frame>
  <!-- ... -->
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Great solution, I was not aware of the `OutlineColor` property. Thank you